# Integral with a constant value

Tags: calculus

Find

$$\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos^2x}{1+a^x} dx$$

$a$ is constant.
My attempt:
Using the rule :

$\int f(x) dx $ from a to b
= $\int f(a+b -x) dx $

We get

$$I = \int \frac{\cos^2x}{1+a^{-x}} dx = \int \frac{a^x \cos^2x }{1+a^x} dx = \int \frac{a^x}{1+a^x}dx- \int \frac{\sin^2x}{1+a^x}dx $$

For the last two integrals i can fo the first one but the second no because it is similar to the original integral

I need a hint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under $x\to -x$, you have
$$I=\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos^2x}{1+a^x} dx=\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos^2x}{1+a^{-x}}dx=\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{a^x\cos^2x}{1+a^x} dx.$$
Hence
$$ 2I=\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{(1+a^x)\cos^2x}{1+a^x} dx=\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^2xdx $$
which is easy to handle.